# Bootstrap Modal Extetnal URL google Map

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have a SearchGoogle html page which opens a google map.I want to load this html file into a modal dialog on the click of a button.

Defined a modal on my main index.jsp page and href the SearchGoogle.html. The content doesnt load up.Any help?
The below page is the remote page i want to load in an Modal Dialog.Have tried remote content loading.It is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/googleMap.css" />
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="script/googleMap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter a location">
<div id="type-selector" class="controls">
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
    <label for="changetype-all">All</label> <input type="radio"
        name="type" id="changetype-establishment"> <label
        for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label> <input
        type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode"> <label
        for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Please show your markup.  Are you using the remote method for loading the modal content?  Please read: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals under the subheading for Options, there is a table that explains the remote option and describes the proper way to load content from a separate html page.

Comment: please find the code editied.This is the remote.html i want to load in a modal dialog.basically its an google map html.The page doesnt load in an Modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look up the [load method in the jQuery API doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/), it says that the load method uses innerHTML to parse the page to be loaded and that:

> During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`,
>   `<title>`, or `<head>` elements.

I suggest putting the `googleMap.css` on the modal page and moving your scripts in the page above to the body tag like this:

**HTML for the page to be loaded (which I'm calling remote.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Map</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Google Map Modal Title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
    <div id="type-selector" class="controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
      <label for="changetype-all">All</label> <input type="radio"
        name="type" id="changetype-establishment"> <label
        for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label> <input
        type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode"> <label
        for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="script/googleMap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML for the page with the modal:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Add the googleMap.css on this page -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/googleMap.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <!-- The contents of remote.html will be injected here.  Don't forget to wrap your content in the modal-header, modal-body, and modal-footer classes! -->  
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep.that did the trick.i got it to atleast load it in modal but the map does not seem to load at all.(only the textbox and radio load up).It might be the resize problem?

Comment: can you get the map to load on it's own?  i mean just by loading the page directly?

Comment: yes.I am able to run the map without any issues.Posting the JS here.